# Strange compiler error when using shared_ptr and make_shared

Tags: c++11

I have the following code:

First line is line number 182

```
void FanBookServer::postRequest(const shared_ptr<Fan> fan){
    auto newPost = std::shared_ptr<FanBookPost>::make_shared(fan);
    posts.insert(newPost->getId(), *newPost);
}
```

For which I get the following errors:

```
FanBookServer.cpp: In member function ‘void mtm::FanBookServer::postRequest(std::shared_ptr<mtm::Fan>)’:
FanBookServer.cpp:183:17: error: ‘make_shared’ is not a member of ‘std::shared_ptr<mtm::FanBookPost>’
FanBookServer.cpp:183:62: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) is a function belong to namespace `std`, not a member of  `std::shared_ptr<T>`. the error message is already very clear about the second part.

it should be `std::make_shared<FanBookPost>(fan)`

---

and your code doesn't looks right. why you need to use `shared_ptr`? you should be able to do

```
FanBookPost newPost{fan};
posts.insert(newPost.getId(), newPost);
```

---

and you should pass `const shared_ptr<Fan> &fan` not just `const shared_ptr<Fan> fan` to avoid copy `shared_ptr`